# What is cleaner way to default tab on another page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Using MVC 3:
I have a summary page that gives a list of sections with no of questions and how many answered in each one.
I want to add hyperlink to each section in order for users to go back to any section that is incomplete?
example (page: question/summary):

```
<div><a href="question/quiz#1">Section 1</a></div><div>Total Questions: 10</div><div>Answered questions: 8</div>
<div><a href="question/quiz#2">Section 2</a></div><div>Total Questions: 10</div><div>Answered questions: 9</div>
```

**Would it be a good idea to use Request.Querystring(x), anchor or other to grab the section id from the url?**

The jquery snippet (and psuedo code) on the previous page is like this:

```
 i = @Request.QueryString("id");
 selectStep(i);

 function selectStep(i) {
                // menu nav
                $("#steps a").removeClass("current");
                $("#stepDesc" + i).addClass("current");
                $("#currentstep").val("#step" + (i));

                // display prev and next button
                if (i == 0) {
                    $("#Next").show();
                    $("#Previous").hide();
                }
                else if (i == count - 1) {
                    $("#Next").hide();
                    $("#Previous").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#Next").show();
                    $("#Previous").show();
                }
            }
```

**Select Step function will show or hide the div for the specific section. what is the best way to approach this?**